# mongodb (compund) index on hashmap field results in inconsistent (count) query result

Tags: mongodb, indexing, hashmap, field

I have a document with a field "ia", it's a HashMap (with key value pair) in my java entity.

The mongo document **PlayerAttribute** looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f8c4cbcd757bd40da8a0c6"),
    "gameId" : "XYZ",
    "ia" : {
        "CrashesCount" : "0",
        "HardCurrencyOwned" : "7898",
        "LastNotificationsId" : "12",
        "Level" : "11",
        "PvpRacesPlayed" : "0",
        "PvpRaiting_FreeStyle" : "1200",
        "PvpRaiting_Motocross" : "1200",
        "PvpRaiting_SpeedAndStyle" : "1200",
        "PvpRaiting_StepUp" : "1200",
        "PvpRank" : "0"
    },
    "lastSessionExpireTime" : ISODate("2013-07-31T12:31:33.966Z"),
    "lastSessionStartTime" : ISODate("2013-07-31T12:31:27.975Z"),
    "name" : "abc123",
    type : null
}
```

This is the index definition for the collection,

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "effectiveDate" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "effectiveDate",
            "dropDups" : false,
            "sparse" : false
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "endDate" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "endDate",
            "dropDups" : false,
            "sparse" : false
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "gameId" : 1,
                    "name" : 1
            },
            "unique" : true,
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "pa_gid_n_unique_idx"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "gameId" : 1,
                    "ia" : 1,
                    "name" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "pa_gid_iattr_n_idx"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "gameId" : 1,
                    "lastSessionExpireTime" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "player.PlayerAttribute",
            "name" : "pa_gid_lset_idx"
    }
]
```

This is the query I used from mongo shell,

**db.PlayerAttribute.find({"gameId":"XYZ", "attributes.CrashesCount" : "0"}).count();**

First time it gives me the result greater than zero (but that is incorrect. For eg., if there are 7 docs match the query, it would say 6) and the next subsequent times it gives 0 and this happens for 5 to 10 minutes.

After about 5 to 10 minutes, it gives the non zero number again (one time) and next few times it is zero.

When I deleted this index ("name" : "pa_gid_iattr_n_idx"), it gives correct count all the time.

Any idea why this index on hashmap field ("name" : "pa_gid_iattr_n_idx") makes mongo to produce incorrect and inconsistent result?

Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: Please post the query you are using and maybe the whole code block that has the problem

Comment: Hi, the collection name is PlayerAttribute and this is the query that I used,  **db.PlayerAttribute.find({"gameId":"XYZ", "attributes.CrashesCount" : "0"}).count();**  And this is happening in mongo shell as well not just in the code.

Comment: I've updated my original post with accurate document and index definition with the query that I used.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite explain why it would sometimes show a result, and sometimes not. This sounds like a bug so please make sure you're running the latest MongoDB version (2.4.5 at the time of writing this). If you can still reproduce it then, please file an issue at http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER — make sure to provide both the query, index creation and sample data set that shows the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

1. Deleting and recreating the index
2. Repair the database by running the mongo repair tool
3. Upgrade to mongo 2.4.5 if not already on it.